# Make A Next Button For More More Data?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Hi dear friends,
            I hope u are all fine.
I want to make a next button for getting more data from mysql database.
For example:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 0,7");
```

It get 7 rows.For next data code is that.
 `$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 7,7");`

I can i do that using ajax.
As you can see in many website like facebook,When you click on comment it give a limited 
comment and when you click on more comment it give more and so on.In this proccess you can see
that the other content of page does not change.It means it can use ajax and how can I do that in ajax.
Please help me.Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you set the content of a div with the output of a PHP script.

Comment: i assume you will need two variables - one for your database count (limit) and one for what to show on screen
so you can get 7 items from database and only show 3 of them

Comment: see this link: http://julienrenaux.fr/2012/10/04/create-a-load-more-widget-using-php-ajax-mootools-bootstrap-and-mustache-js/

Comment: For the love of god stop using `mysql_*` functions and switch to `PDO` or `mysqli_*`

Answer (score 0):

your ajax would be something like this

```
var numberOfdata = 0;

$('#button').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'load.php',
        data: {
            'limit' : numberOfdata,
            // other data ...
        },
        type : 'post',
        // other parameters...
    }).success(function (data) {
        // adding data to your website
        numberOfdata += 7;
    });    
});
```

and in your server side, you could do something like this

```
... other operations
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table LIMIT " . $_POST['limit'] . ",7"); 
... continuting the work
```

Note: You should be able to handle SQL injections on your own.

**Edit**: please note that mysql_query is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You have to send the current comments count via Ajax, get the new ones from the response and display them.

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.pagination-more').click(function() {
        var current_comments_count = $(this).data("current_comments_count");

        $.ajax({ 
            type: "POST",
            url: "pagination/pagination_ajax_more.php",
            data: { "limit_start":current_comments_count },
            beforeSend:  function() {
                $('a.pagination-more').html('<img class="loading-gif" src="pagination/loading.gif" />'); 
            },
            success: function(html){ 
                $("#more").remove(); // This is the "More" button. It is appended to the end again in the 'html' variable
                $("ul#updates").append(html);
                if($("a#end")[0]) {
                    $("div#more").remove();
                }
            }
        }); 

        return false;
    });
});
```

On the PHP side you just get $limit_start, get results from the database and echo the html like:

```
$limit_start = $_POST['limit_start'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table` LIMIT 0, $limit_start");
$current_comments_count = mysql_num_rows($query);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` LIMIT $limit_start, 7");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) { 
    echo '<li>
            blah blah...
          </li>';
}

if(mysql_num_rows($query) == 7)  
    echo '<div id="more"><a data-current_comments_count="$current_comments_count" class="button pagination-more" href="#">More</a></div>';
else
    echo '<div id="more"><a id="end" class="button pagination-more" href="#">The button will be removed from jQuery...</a></div>';
```

Of course it is strongly recommended to secure your application and not to use only `mysql_query()`. This code is working but I removed some other stuff and didn't test it now. So, some errors may occur.